# Javascript RegEx for these email rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm awful at Regular Expressions and need to do client side validation of a field.

What would be the Regular expression to test for a valid email address based on these rules:

E-mail addresses must have the following properties:

1. An @ sign.
2. At least one period (no two consecutively).
3. At least one character between the @ and the first period.
4. At least one character after the last period.

Thanks in advance.

-Seth

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=email+regex

Comment: does not googling "regexp email" help -> http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html?

Comment: Tip: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+email

Comment: Thanks, I have never used google before... I purposefully noted that I am awful with RegEx's, and as the rules above were put in a functional spec I wanted input from the stackoverflow user base to make sure that all properties are satsifed, but I guess asking for feedback with multiple solutions and sometimes resources for better understanding is the exact opposite of what Stack Overflow is all about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a regex for this, at least do it right:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

This regex was taken from [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), which you should definitely read in its entirety.

Comment: +1 @OP The key part of the article being the bit that says *Well, there is an official definition, but it's hardly fool-proof.*

*The official standard is known as RFC 2822. It describes the syntax that valid email addresses must adhere to. You can (but you shouldn't--read on) implement it with this regular expression...*

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){  
   var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/;  
   return emailPattern.test(elementValue);  
}
```

taken from that [article](http://www.zparacha.com/validate-email-address-using-javascript-regular-expression/). As you realize, it does only accept one dot after the @.

@edit: according to [another article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), a more standard conform variant would be:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])
```

Its tradeoff are explanined in the article too. Worth reading!